# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown - C#

Tags: c#, blob, parquet

My requirements are:

1. Read parquet file (File size is 270 MB or more)
2. Convert the above read data into any user readable format file (eg: json)
3. Upload the above readable format file into Azure blob.

I'm able to read the file by using `ChoJSONWriter` and store it back into `StringBuilder`. Now I have to convert it to either a byte array or a stream so that I can upload it to Azure in json. But while converting it to a byte array or `toString()` or a stream, I'm getting an exception of type `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

Here is my code.

```
StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();

using (var r = new ChoParquetReader(FILE_NAME))
{
    using(var w = new ChoJSONWriter(json))
    w.Write(r);
}

Console.WriteLine("capacity: " + json.Capacity);
Console.WriteLine("Max capac : " + json.MaxCapacity);

byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json.ToString());
```

here getting memory out of exception issue.

When I check `StringBuilder.Capacity` then I see its value as `2147483008`, and `StringBuilder.MaxCapacity` value is `2147483647`.

Please suggest any open source packages to read huge parquet and as well as to convert read parquet data into any user readable format and upload back to azure blob.

Comment: You can use `ChoJSONWriter` to write to temp file on disk (probably json will be much larger than source) or you can use to write to `MemoryStream` (still if it's too large you can get OutOfMemoryException).

Comment: I have achieved by using MemoryStream instead  StringBuilder .
But now the challenge is, it took 55 mins to complete the action. 

MemoryStream jsonMS = new MemoryStream ();
using (var r = new ChoParquetReader(FILE_NAME))
{
    using(var w = new ChoJSONWriter(jsonMS ))
    w.Write(r);
}

//To complete above execution, it took 55 mins.. Any help on how to read the huge file fast would be appreciate.